# Multiple images in a listView

Tags: .net, listview

Can I show multiple images in a ListView ( .NET only )
In other words more than one column should be an image column
I cant seem to find any way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) (an open source wrapper around a .NET ListView) has exactly that feature.

The list has to be custom drawn, then you a [ImagesRenderer](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/ownerDraw.html#imagesrenderer) to draw 0 or more images in the one column. That gives a column that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think that this is a limitation with the "out-of-the-box" list view.

You can try using (or looking at the code to see how they managed to do it) the Extended List view from code project:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/EXListView.aspx